# Error with expected an indented block, any one know?

Tags: python

```
a = "aabb"

words = list(a)
new_words = []

count = 1

for i in range(0,len(words)-1):

    if words[i] == words[i+1]:

        count = count + 1

        if i+2 == len(words):
            print words[i+1],count


    else: 
        print words[i],count
        count = 1
```

Comment: Please format your code because it is *vital* to your particular question and please post the complete error. Finally, actually have a body with a question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a file with mixed tabs and spaces and it's confusing you vs the interpreter.  Replace all the tab characters in your file with spaces and then correctly indent the program.

Comment: It might help to run the program with `python -t` which will warn on mixed tabs and spaces. Using `-tt` will make it an error (that's also the default in Python 3).

Comment: @Don: If this answer solved your problem, please "accept" it by clicking the checkmark on the left.  Welcome to Stack Overflow.